# php simpleImage class catch exception error

Tags: php

SimpleImage class not catching exceptions when load image here is the code:

```
public function load($filename) {
        //echo $filename; exit;
    $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
    $this->image_type = $image_info[2];

    if ($this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
        $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    } elseif ($this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
        $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
    } elseif ($this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
        $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not catching the exception the last else would be to catch the exception if it does not meet the condition. here is the updated code.

```
public function load($filename) {
        //echo $filename; exit;
    $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
    $this->image_type = $image_info[2];

    if ($this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
        $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    } elseif ($this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
        $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
    } elseif ($this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
        $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
    } else {
        throw new Exception("The file you're trying to open is not supported");
    }
}
```

I think this will solve.

Comment: Check if `$image_info` is array.otherwise It may produce error if filename is not an image file or unable to read as image.